# How to simplify this nested code with lots of loops

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion

I'm struggling to simplify a piece of nested code, without success, though.

Every time I have to deal with recursion, I'm having a hard time. If anyone can help me with that, I'll be really happy :)

Here's the beast :

```
const solutions: Solution[] = []

for (const sol of [currentSolution]) {
    const solutionsFirstPieceOnly = findSolutionsWithOneMorePiece({currentSolution: sol, pieceSet: currentPieceSet})
    for (const sol1 of solutionsFirstPieceOnly) {
        const solutionsSecondRank = findSolutionsWithOneMorePiece({currentSolution: sol1, pieceSet: currentPieceSet})
        for (const sol2 of solutionsSecondRank) {
            const solutionsThirdRank = findSolutionsWithOneMorePiece({currentSolution: sol2, pieceSet: currentPieceSet})
            for (const sol3 of solutionsThirdRank) {
                const solutionsFourthRank = findSolutionsWithOneMorePiece({currentSolution: sol3, pieceSet: currentPieceSet})
                for (const sol4 of solutionsFourthRank) {
                    const solutionsFifthRank = findSolutionsWithOneMorePiece({currentSolution: sol4, pieceSet: currentPieceSet})
                    for (const sol5 of solutionsFifthRank) {
                        const solutionsSixthRank = findSolutionsWithOneMorePiece({currentSolution: sol5, pieceSet: currentPieceSet})
                        for (const sol6 of solutionsSixthRank) {
                            const solutionsSeventhRank = findSolutionsWithOneMorePiece({currentSolution: sol6, pieceSet: currentPieceSet})
                            for (const sol7 of solutionsSeventhRank) {
                                const solutionsEighthRank = findSolutionsWithOneMorePiece({currentSolution: sol7, pieceSet: currentPieceSet})
                                for (const sol8 of solutionsEighthRank) {
                                    const solutionsNinethRank = findSolutionsWithOneMorePiece({currentSolution: sol8, pieceSet: currentPieceSet})
                                    solutionsNinethRank.forEach((solution) => {if (solution.length) solutions.push(solution)})
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(solutions)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11922384/1169519

Comment: bit difficult without knowing that `findSolutionsWithOneMorePiece` is or `currentSolution` or what the expected result is ...

Comment: @Teemu not relevant, I think. The code is just generating results based on previous results. Seems to have a depth of 9 but it might just be recursive. Solvable with a loop as well.

Comment: @VLAZ You don't think OP could rewrite their code as really conditionally recursive (using the guidance in the linked post) instead of the defined length loops?

Comment: @Teemu it's not traversing a data structure, it's a traversal of solutions. Each solution can lead to more but requires evaluation. Technically that should be tree-shaped but I do not think it's data-structure shaped. It's not about following properties to get the leafs down the line, it's about generating and eliminating possible paths. Not that I don't think it's a duplicate, just not that specific one. It's more akin to doing chess or tic-tac-toe board. From the shape of the code, I might guess it's a sudoku solver.

Comment: @Teemu with that said, hardly really matters whether it's tree-shaped solution or not. In the end, it seems to just be a BFS search. With limit but, again, I think the limit is not relevant, I'd hazard a guess nine levels are exhaustive. So it can be 1. represented as recursion 2. further simplified to loop 3. can even be converted to DFS to reduce the overhead of generating the entire search space at once. This all is vaguely related to traversing objects as it steps into the same theory of traversal but not, IMO, the same. If anything traversing objects is a subset of this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try make a function that you can use recursively. This way you should be able to achieve the same function as the code in the question.

```
function findSolutionsRecursive(currentSolution, pieceSet, depth, maxDepth) {
    if (depth === maxDepth) {
        return [currentSolution];
    } else {
        let solutions = [];
        const nextSolutions = findSolutionsWithOneMorePiece({ currentSolution, pieceSet });

        for (const nextSolution of nextSolutions) {
            solutions = solutions.concat(findSolutionsRecursive(nextSolution, pieceSet, depth + 1, maxDepth));
        }

        return solutions;
    }
}

const maxDepth = 9;
const solutions = findSolutionsRecursive(currentSolution, currentPieceSet, 0, maxDepth);
```

**Code is not tested**, but might work, or should be able to give you an idea for an approacht

Comment: Thanks for your proposition :) It works really well !

Answer (score 1):

This is a good candidate for a (recursive) generator function:

```
function* iter(solutions: Solution[], pieceSet, remaining=9) {
    if (remaining == 0) {
        yield* solutions.filter(({length}) => length);
        return;  
    }
    remaining--;
    for (const currentSolution of solutions) {
        const newSolutions = findSolutionsWithOneMorePiece({currentSolution, pieceSet});
        yield* iter(newSolutions, pieceSet, remaining);
    }
}

const solutions: Solution[] = [...iter([currentSolution], currentPieceSet)];
```

Comment: If done as iterator, I'd even extract that first part that does the filtering to another one: `function* filter(iterator, predicate)`, so `iter` only generates solutions and then you can do `filter(iter([currentSolution], currentPieceSet), ({length}) => length)`. Keeps the solution more flexible

Comment: thanks for the iterator alternative, I like it :) +1 for @VLAZ suggestion